# Retrieve date for browsed web pages in android from browser history

Tags: android

How do I get the date on which web pages were accesed from browser history in android.
 I can get the url and title index, but am not able to get the date for the browsed web page from it, as Browser.SEARCHES_PROJECTION_DATE_INDEX is not giving the proper info wrt the current date.
 Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION_DATE_INDEX.It is returning long value.
Try following code to get the date

```
    CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(this,
            android.provider.Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI,
            Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION, null, null, null);
    Cursor cursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    long dateTime;
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if (cursor.moveToFirst() && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
    dateTime =Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION_DATE_INDEX));
                cal.setTimeInMillis(dateTime);
    Log.i("Date",cal.getTime().toString());
   }
   }
```

Hope it helps